# Dynamically change width of grid based on container

Tags: html, css

I have a grid consisting of slots 32x32 in size. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pdr8egzghd7wmy/Screenshot%202015-10-25%2023.12.23.png?dl=0

Based on the size of the element that it's in, how can I add/ remove more grid slots to fill it? (Can't ever cut off half way through a grid slot/tile)

Here is my code:

```
<style>
    .drag-item {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('assets/images/objects/desk-1.png');
        background-size: 32px;
        width: 32px; height: 32px;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .drop-target {
        position: absolute;
        width: 480px; height: 480px;
        border:dashed 1px orange;
        background: whitesmoke url('assets/images/objects/grid_64.png') repeat;
        background-size: 32px 32px;

    }
</style>
<div class="panel-body" style="width: 520px; height: 520px;">
        <div class="drop-target">
                <div class="drag-item"></div>
                <div class="drag-item"></div>
                <div class="drag-item"></div>
                <div class="drag-item"></div>
                <div class="drag-item"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.drag-item {
    float: left;
}
```

instead of

```
.drag-item {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will make the items align next to each other and jump into the next line when there's not enough space in the current line.

To ensure the container to always be a square in size, you will need either javascript or a ton of media queries. You can then use `overflow: hidden` on the container to hide any overflowing lines of items or javascript to remove them from the DOM completely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is what I need. I'm trying to keep it as a grid, so I can't have new lines. For example, if we have a 5x5 grid, if there is space for another tile, it'll make the grid 6x6.

Comment: I'm sorry, that this isn't what you wanted to achieve. This is as far as you can get with pure CSS.